# linking cells to other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have attached a link to a sample spreadsheet. In column J, K and L I want to link the contents of b3, b7, b11 into cells j2, j3 and j4 etc. 
same applies also for c3,c7,c11 into cells k2, k3, k4 etc and for
d3, d7, d11 into cells L2, L3 L4 etc.

Ideally I just want to click and drag the contents of j2,k2 and L2 down to show what is in columns b,c and d taking into account the gaps of 4 rows between data

There is a gap of 4 rows between the data in columns J,K and L

I am sure it is an easy formula, I just cant work it out to link them

PS how do I put in an attachemment showing the data

Comment: You can upload a screenshot to a sharing site, e.g. Imgur.com.  Then edit your question to add the link.

Answer (score 0):

In J2, type:

`=OFFSET(B$3,4*(ROW()-2),0)`

Fill this across to L2, and then down to L4, or further if necessary.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bandersnatch, it works, great, so thankyou very much

Comment: You're very welcome, glad to help.  Welcome to SU.

Comment: Hello again I understand what is the b3 and 4 but what is the row()-2,0) mean

Comment: Row() gives the current row. So in row 2, ROW()-2 equals 0, and 4*(ROW()-2) gives 0,4,8 as it is filled down.  OFFSET(reference,rows,columns) starts at reference and returns the cell 0,4,8 etc rows down and 0 columns over.

Comment: Hi there, I am having a little bit of difficulty, am just wondering if merge and center affects the answer. I do have some merge and center cells in my B column in the row spaces between the data ie the 4 rows b/w the cells containing data. hope you can help, Murray

Comment: Also just to confirm, does the 4 represent the no. of rows between the rows with data, and why do you use the multiplication symbol?

Comment: Please read my comment above to understand what the 4 is for. In J3, type =OFFSET(B$3,4,0). If that doesn’t give the value in B7, change the 4 to other numbers until it does. Then comment here and explain what worked.

Comment: Hi, finally worked out the full formula and what all the components of the formula is and what they mean and have got it working in my spreadsheet. Thankyou